# Save one to one association in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

i am trying to save person along with his address. I have one to one mapping between person and address.Person class is having instance of address. When i created the person table address table also got created. Till here no issues. But when i try to save person , address is not getting saved.Here is my mapping file

```
 <hibernate-mapping>

  <class name="com.daasl.Person" table="person">
  <id name="id" type="int">
     <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>

  <property name="name" column="cname" type="string"/>
  <one-to-one name="address" class="com.daasl.Address"/>
  </class>


 <class name="com.daasl.Address" table="Address">
  <id name="id" type="int">
     <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property name="personId"  type="int"/>
  <property name="addressLine1"  type="string"/>

 </class> 

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

i am not sure how create foreign key relationship here (basically i want person id in address table as foreign key to person table) and when i save the data to person table , address should be saved too which is not happening now.Similarily i retrieve data , i should also get the data for address too

Comment: Show us your code. But what's sure is that you shouldn't have a personId (int) field in address, but a person (or type Person) field. This would be the inverse one-to-one association. Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-bidirectional-join-121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your one-to-one relationship seems to be ok. If your Address doesn't get saved when you save the associated Person, is probably because you haven't configured [cascading](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade).

By default, Hibernate doesn't perform any cascading, therefore only the Person will be saved and not the associated entities. You should do something like:

```
<one-to-one name="address" class="com.daasl.Address" cascade="save-update"/>
```

In your Person->Address relationship.

The type of cascading depends on the operation you are performing (save, update, etc) on the Person entity. As per the link above, there are different types of cascading related to such operation - use the one that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. Data is getting saved now in Address table too. But two issues i am facing now are 1) Data  is going inside address table but personid in address table is forign key to personid in person table.Not sure how to define foreign key relationship in above hbm file.2) When i retrieve person with Person p1 = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1); iam expecting the proxy .I mean actual data should be loaded when i do p1.getName. Even address association are eagerly loaded (by default hibernate support lazy loading).Not sure why its is happening like this?

Comment: "1) Data is going inside address table but personid in address table is forign key to personid in person table.Not sure how to define foreign key relationship in above hbm file" 

Not sure what you want to define here. Can you elaborate a bit more? Nevertheless, I would stay away of defining foreign key columns as fields in your entities. If you want to have a reference to the Person in the Address, I would define the inverse side of the relationship in the Address as a OneToOne too. Also, can you show the entities? And lastly, any specific reason for not using annotations rather than XML?

Comment: Gonzalo There is not specific reason of not using annotation.I am new to hibernate . So though XML would better help me in understanding the basics.Do i need to do some configuration to enable annotation or can i straightaway start using it?